# How to integrate the adobe flash player in webview in android?

Tags: android

I am integrate adobe flash player in webview but  getting the error plug in could not supported

```
flashPlayerWebView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        flashPlayerWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        flashPlayerWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        flashPlayerWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
       // flashPlayerWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
     flashPlayerWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Flash/index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

is because not all android phones have flash player so it may not work, i suggest to sorround your code with a try catch like this:

```
    try{
flashPlayerWebView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    flashPlayerWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    flashPlayerWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    flashPlayerWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
   // flashPlayerWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
 flashPlayerWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Flash/index.html");
}catch(Exception e){
Log.i("error","missing flashplayer")}
```

Comment: there is no any error it just showing couldn't load plug-in.if you have any solution please let me know

Comment: What android version is the device?

Comment: I am using kit-kat

Comment: Try installing flash player from the store